# How to obtain access token from azure

Tags: azure, authentication

I am stuck with the authentication to use the REST API for getting subscription billing information from [Resource Usage API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt219003.aspx)

I would like to get help with how to obtain token for non interactive clients. I chose to use the REST API since azure client seems to not support Resource Usage API.

As the [Authorization code grant (interactive clients)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service#request-an-access-token) describes , I have called the request with my subscription id but token is not returned properly.

```
[root@visual src]# curl -XPOST https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx/oauth2/token -d ""
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: 32981285-a021-45c3-8d2f-62db49d2c2f1\r\nCorrelation ID: d88849dd-20f9-462e-9ce9-66b6fde0170e\r\nTimestamp: 2017-03-04 04:06:44Z","error_codes":[90014],"timestamp":"2017-03-04 04:06:44Z","trace_id":"32981285-a021-45c3-8d2f-62db49d2c2f1","correlation_id":"d88849dd-20f9-462e-9ce9-66b6fde0170e"}[root@visual src]#
```

How can I obtain the token?

Comment: I don't any request body parameters in your request. Can you include them per the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

A token will not be returned if you don't supply some credentials :)

If you want to do a non-interactive request with client credentials for example, your request must contain (in URL-encoded form format):

- grant_type=client_credentials
- client_id=your-app-client-id
- client_secret=your-app-client-secret
- resource=resource-uri-for-api-you-want-the-token-for

The resource URI could be for example `https://graph.windows.net/` for the Azure AD Graph API.

You can also get tokens with the *password* grant if you wish to use a username and password. In that case, you must send:

- client_id, client_secret and resource as above
- grant_type=password
- username=your-username
- password=your-password